# Does Windows 8 RT have a way to setup VPN configuration settings in an app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, vpn

There are several VPN Client applications on iOS and Android environments. Is there any way to build a VPN Client for the Windows 8 RT apps?

I've found discussion here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows?query=vpn&rq=meta:Search.MSForums.ForumID(fc9915fa-bd55-4c15-9a72-9956efee4a7c)+site:microsoft.com&rn=Windows+8+Networking+Forum

There's a way to access and setup this information on the Windows 8 desktopusing Routing and Remote Access (found here):
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Routing-and-Remote-Access-ba17e417#content

Is there a way to modify user settings on their device to setup VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with prime security issues around allowing an app to do such a change - my best guess would be that the winRT is not designed to allow apps to modify Remote Desktop settings on a given machine.

You can ask the user to do the changes manually: To see if remote desktop is enabled at all, just check for whether the Terminal Services service is running, using [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible for a user to modify their Settings for VPN connection?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6cde20/enable-user-for-changing-internet-settings-in-windows-8/

This may be of use it shows you how to modify the settings in order to change internet settings , I would assume vpn is in there somewhere.